# Dragging image file appears on incorrect line

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2007

I have MS Word 2007, every time I drag an Image from a folder (lets say a .PNG file) into my Word Document the Image will always appear on the line the cursor **was** when I left Word, not where I dragged the Image to.

Here are images to help you understand:

[image]

The picture ended up where my cursor was left at:

[image]

This is more for my curiosity than to actually solve the issue because it really isnt that hard to leave your cursor at the spot you want the image to be, its just something that has always bugged me about MS Word.

**Questions**

1. Is this a setting, a defect, intended?
2. Does this occur on other versions of MS Word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the gritty details seeing as I am not one of the developers of MS Word, but as a programmer who has worked with text before I can say that i am not surprised the Image inserts at your cursor.

What is a [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(computers))?

It really is what it sounds like, a positional indicator within a document in this case. Since rich text documents (at its core what a word document is) are a series of characters which have an end (Carraige Return + Line Feed) your mouse pointer cannot be mapped  into the document by pixel but rather by line. Why MS Word doesn't make a "best guess" is beyond me, but I assume it is that way by design. it would be quite fusterating if not ambiguous for the application to "guess" where my picture should go when I want it to go to a specific place.

What better way to indicate an exact position than with a cursor.

Comment: That is probably what is happening and makes sense, I guess I just assumed that because they show the indicator (the dashed vertical line) of where you are dragging the image to it would go there.

Comment: What you see is not always what is there when working with microsoft word. there is a lot of formatting going on behind the scenes. The indicator may be to indicate where word will "try" to insert the object. Depending on the objects size relative to the text, it may or may not actually move there.

Comment: I know the Insert -> Picture uses your cursor position and I guess the drag-n-drop probably calls the same function/method they implemented.  Your answer makes sense, so I will accept it.  Just angers me slightly that they would bother to show you where they are going to _"try"_ to put the image but they really don't try at all and just use the cursor position.

Comment: @Jason, I think you are confusing the caret and the cursor. In any case you are right it looks like Word is inserting the image whereever the caret is placed. There is a promising option under Advanced settings "Insert/Paste picutures as" and you can choose to select something floating like Square or In front, however the same behavior still remains. There might be a macro function you could override such as OnDragDrop and implement the functionality yourself.

Comment: @Adam, you are right, caret would be the more appropriate term.